# Que disent les français pour se corriger en parlant ?

Tags: expressions, oral

Alors en anglais on dit « or » dans ce contexte ("I bought some more milk. Or, bread") donc qu'est-ce qu’on dirait en français ?

J’ai vu « ou alors » sur wordreference mais je ne suis pas sûr si on utilise ça si souvent. Merci !

Comment: Pour se corriger ou pour ajouter ? L'exemple n'est pas très clair.

Comment: Je lis/ecoute "err" souvent en anglais.

Answer (score 11):

#### Dans la conversation courante :

- > J'ai acheté du lait — **euh**, du pain.
- > J'ai acheté du lait — **enfin**, du pain.

**Je veux dire** s'emploie aussi volontiers : 'j'ai acheté du lait — **euh, je veux dire**, du pain.' Il s'utilise tout à fait comme *'I mean'* en anglais.

Je ne crois pas qu'il faille employer 'ou alors', parce que cela donne l'impression que le locuteur hésite (*…milk? or was it bread?*)

#### À l'écrit ou dans un contexte plus soutenu :

- > J'ai acheté du lait — **ou plutôt** du pain.
- > J'ai acheté du lait — **pardon,** du pain.
- > J'ai acheté du lait — **que dis-je ?** du pain.

Utilisé à des fins stylistiques, ce procédé se nomme [épanorthose](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89panorthose), la page wikipédia offre quelques exemples.

Answer (score 5):

Very informal " je veux dire" , " j'veux dire" , maybe not sponteaneously, but after having noticed that the person one is talking  to does not understand what has been said or seems to disapprove.

" Je peux utiliser ton PC deux minutes ? ...j'veux dire, ton Mac."

Answer (score 1):

Si tu veux corriger ce que tu viens de dire, c'est à dire qu tu rends compte que tu t'es trompé dans ta phrase tu peux utiliser "ou plutôt". Avec ton exemple :

> J'ai acheté du lait... ou plutôt du pain.